# Asp.net Web Api Authentication and password encryption

Tags: asp.net, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

I have a autentication with the web api working, but is using the email and password to autenticate, how can i change so that web api uses a username field and password for the autentication?
Another thing, how can i change the encrytion method for the password?

The Autentication is made this away:

```
public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password")
        };

        Settings.Serverdown = false;

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://192.168.44.22:56479/Token");
        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(6000);
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var jwt = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Settings.LoginSucess = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        Settings.Username = username;

        JObject jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jwt);

        var accessToken = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("access_token");
        Settings.AccessToken = accessToken;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        XFToast.LongMessage("Cant reach the server");
        Settings.Serverdown = true;
    }

    var accessToken2=Settings.AccessToken;

    return accessToken2; 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you store email under username filed in the db? I hope not. I am asking because this is the default implementation of AccountController.

Comment: Yes  i using the default implementation, i dont know how to change.